# How do I get a string to be displayed after a method is called in an entire printf method?

Tags: java

I want the strings " (pounds)" at the end to be displayed, but my scanner class keeps leaving them out. Tell me why this is happening?

```
   System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f \n", person.getWeight(), " (pounds)");
   System.out.printf("Height: %.1f \n", person.getHeight(), " (inches)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show in your format where string `%s` containing units should be placed like

```
System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f %s\n", person.getWeight(), "(pounds)");
System.out.printf("Height: %.1f %s\n", person.getHeight(), "(inches)");
```

Or you can place units in your format manually

```
System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f (pounds)\n", 1.1);
System.out.printf("Height: %.1f (inches)\n", .2);
```

BTW instead of `\n` you can use `%n` to produce OS specific set of separators like `\r\n` for Windows. It will produce same result as `System.lineSeparator()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?

```
System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f (pounds)\n", person.getWeight());
System.out.printf("Height: %.1f (inches)\n", person.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it?

```
System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f (pounds)\n", person.getWeight(), );
```

Or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 System.out.printf("Weight: %.1f (pounds) \n", person.getWeight());
```